# Animating dropdown menu with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I am animating a menu here http://jsfiddle.net/5Lscg/ with jQuery slide but have trouble with first hover. It just displays without animation. All sub levels work ok.

**JQuery Code:**

```
    $("li").on('mouseenter', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().hide().show('slide', {
            direction: "down"
        }, function () {

            // $(this).css('display', 'block');

        });

    }).on('mouseleave', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().hide('slide', {
            direction: "up"
        }, function () {

            // $(this).css('display', 'none');

        });
    });
```

Seems like I have a css bug somewhere but I cant find it. I would be grateful if you could take a look and try to find out where the issue is. 4 eyes are always better than 2 :)

Any help is appreciated.

**Just tested in FF as advised and it works well but IE, Chrome , Opera are freaking out**

Comment: I feel the animation is working well, could you just point out where exactly are you seeing the issue

Comment: @dreamweiver, hover over Sub Holder , the first level dropdown does not animate. P.S. why did you remove "Thank you" word  from my post ?

Comment: its working fine for me, i`m running on firefox 27.0.1. Regarding the edit, formal greetings dont seem good  on SO.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: it is working in FF only , IE , Opera , Chrome dont work, will edit the post.

Comment: hey look 

try it with jquery 1.9.1 version and jquery ui  1.9.2 version

this may help you

Comment: @mahmoudnezarsarhan thank you for suggestion , I tested all versions and switched UI but same thing

Answer (score 1):

it works fine for me !!

Your css is fine

also your jquery

I'm sure that your problem is cross-browser problem , not a coding one

try it with another browser

Comment: ha! crazy  thing. Chrome is messing with it, FF works fine. thank you!

Comment: IE, Opera also freaking out , strange